# How to specify a custom Media Client in Atlaskit especially @atlaskit/editor-core

Tags: reactjs, typescript, prose-mirror, atlaskit

I'm trying to use @atlaskit/editor-core in my own project and want to specify my own Fileserver/MediaClient. Atlassian does provide a function, where I could mock the client and instead of really mocking it injecting my own client this way... but is this really the best option?

Since the documentation on @atlaskit/editor-core is fairly small, I do not know where else to look...

Findings so far:
with the following line the mocking can be enabled.

```js
import { mediaMock } from '@atlaskit/media-test-helpers'
mediaMock.enable()
```

Minimal Example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { MediaProvider } from '@atlaskit/editor-common';
import { Editor } from '@atlaskit/editor-core';
import { MediaClientConfig } from '@atlaskit/media-core';
import { mediaMock, mediaPickerAuthProvider } from '@atlaskit/media-test-helpers';

mediaMock.enable();


// Crreating basic MediaProvider
const collection = 'sample-collection';
const mediaClientConfig: MediaClientConfig = {
  authProvider: mediaPickerAuthProvider(),
};

const mediaProvider = Promise.resolve<MediaProvider>({
  uploadParams: { collection },
  viewMediaClientConfig: mediaClientConfig,
  uploadMediaClientConfig: mediaClientConfig,
});

export const EditorMinimal = () => {
  return (
    <Editor
      appearance="full-page"
      media={{
        provider: mediaProvider,
        allowResizing: true,
        allowMediaSingle: true,
        useMediaPickerPopup: false,
        allowDropzoneDropLine: true,
        isCopyPasteEnabled: true,
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Any link, direction, advise or starting point will be appreciated!!

Comment: why do you enable the `mediaMock`? Just wondering if you wouldn't mind commenting here about that decision some more for added context since it seems to be an important moving part.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this using my own answer at https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/atlaskit-editor-core-custom-file-endpoint-file-upload-service/45558